# Can combineReducers work with extra actions?

Tags: redux

What I want is the root reducer combine other reducers, and listen to extra actions. I've find the docs, but I can not get any information.

Here is some pseudo code.

```
const root1 = combineReducers({
  reducer1,
  reducer2,
  reducer3,
  reducer4
});

function root2(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_DATA:
      return _.assign({}, initState, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

merge(root1, root2);
```

The only way I figure out is to drop combineReducers:

```
function root(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_DATA:
      return _.assign({}, initState, action.data);
    case ...: return ...;
    case ...: return ...;
    case ...: return ...;
    default: return state;  
  }
}
```

Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: In your first code snippet, why wouldn't `root2` simply be another argument to `combineReducers`?

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh you mean `combineReducers({..., root2})` ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant.

Comment: @DavidL.Walsh I can't. If I do that, only `roo2` will update when the `LOAD_DATA` action dispatched. What I want is update the whole state when `LOAD_DATA` action dispatched.

Comment: I don't follow. You can have multiple parts of the state listen to the same action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use `combineReducers()` with multiple reducers while also having an action that rebuilds your *entire* application state. Admittedly, that is a bit of a strange design decision and does not scale very well with more complex apps, but you obviously have a use-case. If you want to do something like that you have two choices.

### Option 1: Divide up action

It is totally valid to listen for the same action type within multiple reducer functions. This is the most straightforward approach, although it involves more repetition. You would just break out each piece of state returned by your action into the individual reducer functions it applies to.

For instance, if this was your entire application state

```
{
    foo: {},
    bar: {}
}
```

And your action type that rebuilt the entire application state was `LOAD_DATA`, you could do this

```
function foo (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_DATA':
            return {...state, action.result.foo}
    }
}

function bar (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_DATA':
            return {...state, action.result.bar}
    }
}

const root = combineReducers({
  foo,
  bar
});
```

With that, both `foo` and `bar` in your state would always get rebuilt with the corresponding data coming from the *same* action.

### Option 2: Build Custom combineReducers()

There is nothing stopping you from building your own version of `combineReducers()`. If you watch [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-implementing-combinereducers-from-scratch?series=getting-started-with-redux) on building a `combineReducers()` function from scratch, you'll see that the logic in place is not that complicated. You would just have to listen for the specific action type and return the entire state from that action if it matched. Here's a version of that I built by looking at the [current source for `combineReducers()`](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/src/combineReducers.js) and then working the 2 util functions into that function

```
function combineReducers(reducers) {
  var fn = (val) => typeof val === 'function';
  var finalReducers = Object.keys(reducers).reduce((result, key) => {
    if (fn(reducers[key])) {
      result[key] = reducers[key]
    }
    return result
  }, {});

  return function combination(state = {}, action) {
    if (action.type === 'LOAD_DATA') {
        return completeStateReducer(action)
    } else {
        var hasChanged = false
        var fn = (reducer, key) => {
          var previousStateForKey = state[key]
          var nextStateForKey = reducer(previousStateForKey, action)
          if (typeof nextStateForKey === 'undefined') {
            var errorMessage = getUndefinedStateErrorMessage(key, action)
            throw new Error(errorMessage)
          }
          hasChanged = hasChanged || nextStateForKey !== previousStateForKey
          return nextStateForKey
        }
        var finalState = Object.keys(finalReducers).reduce((result, key) => {
            result[key] = fn(finalReducers[key], key)
            return result
          }, {})

        return hasChanged ? finalState : state
    }
  }
}

function completeStateReducer(action) {
    return action.result;
}
```

Outside of merging those util functions back in, the only thing I really added was the bit about listening for the `LOAD_DATA` action type and then calling `completeStateReducer()` when that happens instead of combining the other reducer functions. Of course, this assumes that your `LOAD_DATA` action actually returns your entire state, but even if it doesn't, this should point you in the right direction of building out your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

First, `combineReducers` is merely a utility function that simplifies the common use case of "this reducer function should handle updates to this subset of data".  It's not required.

Second, that looks like pretty much the exact use case for https://github.com/acdlite/reduce-reducers.  There's an example here: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/749#issuecomment-164327121

```
export default reduceReducers(
  combineReducers({
    router: routerReducer,
    customers,
    stats,
    dates,
    filters,
    ui
  }),
  // cross-cutting concerns because here `state` is the whole state tree
  (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'SOME_ACTION':
        const customers = state.customers;
        const filters = state.filters;
        // ... do stuff
    }
  }
);
```

Also, I give an example of using `reduceReducers` in the "Structuring Reducers" section of the Redux docs: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html .

Comment: Yep, repo moved.  Updated the issue link, and added a link to the "Structuring Reducers" docs section I wrote as well.

Comment: Nice! This shows loading a state slice - will reduceReducers work with resetting it too? If I want to reset a whole state slice to defaults defined in reducer1, ...?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is "yes".  The key idea is that reducers are just functions - you can combine them any way you want to accomplish the result you want.